# Answer to question cut in the middle in question view, in full in edit view

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serverfault cut off/truncated on long post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post)

When trying to view my answer to [For home projects, can Mercurial or Git (or other DVCS) provide more advantages over Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218471/for-home-projects-can-mercurial-or-git-or-other-dvcs-provide-more-advantages-o/1218657#1218657) question (using Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050923) I see my answer cut in the middle of word; it ends with " it while merging it can deal wit".

But when I go to the [edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1218657/edit) for this question, or [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1218657/list), thinking that I have by accident removed content while editing, and hoping to be able to resurrect deleted contents from earlier revisions... I see the answer in full.  The fragment that ends in 'question' view continues: "  it while merging it can deal with the case where one side renamed file (and other similar cases related to renaming).".  The answer ends with "Take a look also at http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/ site."

WTF?

Comment: Edit the post, add a space at the end. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post

Comment: +1 to Ian Elliott; I just did it and it works now.

Comment: Thanks for a way to fix it; still I think that this occurence means that there can be some bug in rendering and caching engine that StackOverflow uses...

Comment: There *was* a bug. It has since been fixed, and the issue now only affects old posts which now have to be fixed manually.

Comment: @Ian Elliott, I wonder how many people on a programming site are going to buy that a formatting bug can only be fixed manually. ;-)