# Answer not fully rendered

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown-rendering

I noticed that part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310914/218196) is not rendered.

It looks like

> [image]

whereas the text box and the preview clearly show the full content:

> [image]
>   `~~ snip ~~`
>   [image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Oded just fixed it. Jay for Oded!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Known issue with old posts - the renderer at the time had a bug and partial HTML was cached in the answer table for it.

Any edit to the answer will sort it (and has - I just opened for edit and saved).

Other threads on meta with the same issue (I am sure there are more):

- [Answer to question cut in the middle in question view, in full in edit view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14097/140505)
- [Serverfault cut off/truncated on long post?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/129)

Comment: Ok, I did not know that :) I only thought there might be a strange character after `in`, so I removed it, inserted a space, but it did not create a new revision (which means I actually did not make any changes). Thanks!

Comment: @Felix - I wouldn't expect most people to know that... I saw a similar question a while ago and remembered the answer.